# How to count the number of objects associated with an S4 class

Tags: r, r-s4

I have a program that would like to reference the number of objects created in the class "bucket." How can I count the number of objects created within this class? Below is the class creator line.

```
setClass("bucket", 
         slots = list(elements = c("character"), 
                      targets = c("numeric"), 
                      type = "numeric", 
                      uncert_Dist = "numeric", 
                      ranking = c("numeric"), 
                      confidence_Int = "numeric", 
                      wildcard = "numeric"))
```

Comment: Not entirely sure this is what you want but `length(slotNames(new("bucket")))` would  return the number of slots in your object

Answer (score 2):

To list the class of all objects, you can use

```
sapply(mget(ls()), class)
```

To count how many have class ==  'bucket'

```
sum(sapply(mget(ls()), inherits, 'bucket'))
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP want the length of the "slots" list?

Comment: Hmm - perhaps.  I was trying to interpret the phrase `number of objects created in the class "bucket."`  If I misunderstood, perhaps OP can clarify

Comment: `sapply(ls(), class)` will always be character, think you need to use `get` i.e. `unlist(sapply(lapply(ls(), get), class))`

Comment: I meant the objects created in the class, not the number of slots. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most appropriate way to do this (that would fit nicely with other features in R and would be reasonably intuitive) would be to define a method for `length` (which is an internal generic function, so you can write S4 methods for it).

```
setMethod(
  "length",
  signature(x="bucket"),
  function(x) length(x@elements)
)
```

Then if you have a bucket object `z` you just call `length(z)` to find out the number of things in it (just like you would call `length` in any other context).